# Вызов асинхронной функции внутри map

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, асинхронность

Пытаюсь вызвать асинхронную функцию внутри map, но не получается. Что я делаю не так, подскажите, не могу понять.

**АФ:**

```
const GetAdditionalData = async (url) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`url`)
    const json = await response.json()

    return json.data.result 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

**Пример:**

```
try {
  const promises = [1, 2].map(async market => {
    try {

      const data = await GetMarketData(market)
      const onlyOpen = data.filter(x => x[1] === 'open')

      return onlyOpen.map(async item => {
        const url = "..."
        const addData = await GetAdditionalData(url)

        return {
          main: item[0],
          sec: item[1],
          adInfo: GetAdditionalData(url)        
        }

      })

    } catch (error) {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
  })

  Promise.all(promises).then(
    results => {
      res.status(200).send([...results[0], ...results[1]])
    },
    reason => {
      res.status(404).send(reason)
    }
  )
} catch (error) {
  res.status(404).send(error)
}
```

Все идет нормально до момента как я пытаюсь получить доп. инфу(adInfo) из await GetAdditionalData(url).

Comment: `return onlyOpen.map` -> `return Promise.all(onlyOpen.map`

Comment: @nörbörnën, вот я затупок, спасибо дружище.

Comment: `adInfo: await GetAdditionalData(url)` или `adInfo: addData`.